# Is there a integration between crontab and Rundeck?

Tags: cron, rundeck

I'm trying to find a tool where you can easily monitor cronjobs for the company I work at. Rundeck seems like the perfect tool for this but I can't figure out if it's possible to integrate the existing cronjobs into Rundeck. It's too much work to do this manually because there are hundreds of them.

If you now another tool that can do this feel free to recommend!
I'd rather want it to be open source but if it's paid and it works correct I'm open to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rundeck works as a "very enhanced cron replacement" maybe the best approach in your case is to migrate your cron jobs to Rundeck and use the [notification](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/notifications/interface-instructions.html#notification-interface) for monitoring. [This](https://www.endurops.com/2019/03/21/are-you-still-using-cron-in-2019-then-you-need-to-checkout-rundeck/) looks like a good starting point for you, don´t forget to visit the [official documentation](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/01-introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

What Mega mentions is correct, rundeck can be used as a replacement for cron.

Even better, there is no need to configure all of those manually: Rundeck allows you to [import job definitions via API call](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#importing-jobs).

Steps:

1. Get rundeck [installed](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/install/)
2. Set up a job to run one of your cron jobs manually
3. [Export](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/creating-jobs.html#exporting-job-definitions) that job
4. Use a script to make many copies of that file, that each contain a different item from cron*
5. Import all those [files via API call](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#importing-jobs)

*You'll need to change at least the name and workflow (called sequence commands file - you'll be able to see based on the workflow step you configured)